# Unable to open windows 8.1 partitions in Ubuntu 12

Tags: mount, ntfs

This is the error coming. I have shut down windows properly and yet this error comes.

```
Error mounting /dev/sda7 at /media/harshit/Movies and songs: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda7" "/media/harshit/Movies and songs"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda7': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: Besides the duplicate: please read what the notice tells you. All the info you need is in there.

Answer (score 0):

when you shutting down window's 8.1 instead of shutting down through the menu panel, shut it down using force command to do this

1. Press windows button and R key when you are in window's 8.1.
2. when the run prompt up type in that :-
3. `shutdown -s -f -t 00`
4. comment: -s for shutdown, -r for reboot use whichever you required.
5. And press enter
6. And when you reboot into ubuntu you can easily mount windows partition in it.